# Don't Know How to use This Ajax code in my chat application

Tags: c#, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax, chat

This is the Ajax code to be used with my chat application.
I have successfully completed chat application but I need to use ajax so that application make lesser trips to database, BUT I DON't KNOW HOW TO USE THIS CODE WITH MY SIMPLE CHAT APPLICATION.PLEASE SOMEONE EXPLAIN THE USE OF CODE IN DETAIL

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- Reference to google J-Query api.
    You can download and add jquery javasripts files to you soln.-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callService() {
            //url of your web service
            $.ajax('../sessionOut.asmx/GetNewsAndAlerts',
        {
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { },
            complete: function () { },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            type: 'POST',
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                //Function will be called when any error occcured.
                alet(thrownError);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.d) {

                    //Cound not find data.
                }
                else {
                    if (curdata != data.d) {
                        //result of you web method is stored in data.d object. 

                        //TODO : Work with you data here.
                        alert(data.d);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        }
        callService();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind Ajax is to reduce the number of full page refreshes that your web application does. It does not reduce database activity as you mention in your question.

In this case CallService calls a page in this case getnewsandalerts and the success: code is called when the page results are returned to the Ajax call at that point any data returned by the page on the server is available to jquery on the web page in the browser.

Comment: Thank You for your time, You are right, I use meta tag to refresh my page every second, and that why I need to use Ajax to minimise number of refresh

Comment: All I want to understand is that How this Ajax code will apend new chat messages without refreshing whole page

Comment: and where Do I write this Ajax code???? In Aspx page, or in Aspx.cs page, or in .asmx page or in some seperate page?

Comment: The Ajax code is always invoked on the web page client side so in the document ready function you could call the callService code to load the data, it could be in a function that handles a click on a button, it's up to you